# edited how to make nginx pont to my mosquitto broker in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, mqtt

I have an web server with ubuntu 20.04 lets call it mywebsite.com that i've installed nginx and [2 nodered 2 mosquitto 2 grafana those are runing on docker, docker-compose called client1  that contain 1 grafana 1 mosquitto 1 nodered  ]
client_mosquitto ha a local ip address of 192.170.0.5 and use port 60007
here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
     rewrite ^/client1/grafana(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass "http://mywebsite.com:60007/grafana/";
    }

    location /client1/node-red/ {
            rewrite ^/node-red(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://mywebsite.com:60008;
    }
   location /client1/mqtt/ {
            rewrite ^/node-red(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://mywebsite.com:60009;
    }
   }
```

the problem that I am facing is that I can't access my mosquitto broker, so if i send data to my clien1_broker with "mywebsite.com:60009" i don't receive any thing

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64372533/edit) the question to explain how it is different from your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338203/how-to-do-reverse-proxy-on-docker).

Comment: Your post is too confusing to answer correctly.  "web" is the HTTP protocol, "MQTT Broker" is of course the MQTT protocol. It sounds like you expect Nginx to somehow know when you are sending in HTTP and when you are sending MQTT....which it doesn't.  What are you trying to achieve?  Posting your Nginx config would also be a good start.

Comment: That edit still doesn't really help. I included a link in the answer to your last question that explains how to use the NGINX stream system to proxy for MQTT. You can not use the HTTP module.

Comment: thank you very much for you help your link was very helpful